# Aim: Accept input from user for storing a list of items and develop a logic to generate line numbers for the given items.

Tags: java

Aim: Accept input from user for storing a list of items and develop a logic to generate line numbers
for the given items.

The item has the following attributes,
1. Name,
2. Description
3. Line number

Specifications for generating Line numbers:

. The first Page of the list should contain only 4 lines

. The following pages can contain lines to a maximum limit of 9

. Each line number should have its page number along with its line number as an alphabet.
    i.e 6th item on page three should be "3F" where '3' is the page number and 'F' is the line number

. If the description of the item is more than 20 characters long then the description should be printed on the next line
This is critical in determining the line number of an item.

To explain it with an example, if an item is occupying line "2C" and it's description is greater than 20 characters long
then the next item should be having the value "2E" as the item in "2C" occupies the next line "2D" as well

. Now to complicate things, the items should be alphabatically sorted

Comment: Hiii all,can anyone help me in developing this code.

Comment: I am unable to develop a logic for the above program.could you please suggest me the solution.